# Sequelize Nested Include + Where error: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am unable to run a findAll query with a 2 level nested include using a column in the parent field. Here is my Sequelize code

```js
const metaQuestionAnswers = await AuditQuestionAnswer.findAll({
    where: {
      audit_question_id: rootQuestionId,
      meta_question_id: {
        [Op.not]: null,
      },
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: MetaQuestion,
        required: true,
        duplicating: false,
        include: [
          {
            required: true,
            duplicating: false,
            model: MetaQuestionOption,
            as: "options",
            where: {
              id: {
                // I have also tried audit_question_answers.meta_question_option_id but I the same error
                [Op.col]: "AuditQuestionAnswers.meta_question_option_id", 
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

And here is the sql

```sql
SELECT 
  "audit_question_answer"."id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."answer_type", 
  "audit_question_answer"."value", 
  "audit_question_answer"."created_at", 
  "audit_question_answer"."updated_at", 
  "audit_question_answer"."audit_question_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."audit_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."audit_question_option_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."meta_question_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."meta_question_option_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."tech_item_id", 
  "audit_question_answer"."audit_outcome_id", 
  "meta_question"."id" AS "meta_question.id", 
  "meta_question"."index" AS "meta_question.index", 
  "meta_question"."slug" AS "meta_question.slug", 
  "meta_question"."text" AS "meta_question.text", 
  "meta_question"."remediation_text" AS "meta_question.remediation_text", 
  "meta_question"."audit_template_id" AS "meta_question.audit_template_id", 
  "meta_question->options"."id" AS "meta_question.options.id", 
  "meta_question->options"."index" AS "meta_question.options.index", 
  "meta_question->options"."label" AS "meta_question.options.label", 
  "meta_question->options"."score_id" AS "meta_question.options.score_id", 
  "meta_question->options"."meta_question_id" AS "meta_question.options.meta_question_id" 
FROM 
  "audit_question_answers" AS "audit_question_answer" 
  INNER JOIN "meta_questions" AS "meta_question" ON "audit_question_answer"."meta_question_id" = "meta_question"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "meta_question_options" AS "meta_question->options" ON "meta_question"."id" = "meta_question->options"."meta_question_id" 
  AND "meta_question->options"."id" = "AuditQuestionAnswers"."meta_question_option_id" 
WHERE 
  "audit_question_answer"."audit_question_id" = 26996 
  AND "audit_question_answer"."meta_question_id" IS NOT NULL
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "AuditQuestionAnswers"
```

Where am I going wrong here?

I want to only get the `MetaQuestionOptions` that have the same `id` as `auditQuestionAnswer.meta_question_option_id` but I am unable to.

Comment: And why didn't you indicate `audit_question_answer` instead of `AuditQuestionAnswers`?

Comment: @Anatoly I get the same issue. Updated my question

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL with `audit_question_answer `?